# Getting an error while writing a react test using Ant Design: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Title' of '_antd.Typography' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, antd, ts-jest

I'm writing a React test using Ant Design and I'm getting an error. I think it accesses Typography but doesn't understand Title. I tried a few variants like Const {Title}=Typography but it doesn't work. How can I solve it?

Component.js

`import { Typography, Select } from "antd";`

`const {Title,Text} = Typography;`

`const {Option} = Select;`

Component.test.js

`jest.mock("antd", () => ({}));`

[image]

Comment: Why did you mock `antd`?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I'm getting a very long red error in Terminal. So I thought of mocking antd as a solution.

Comment: If you remove the mock,  is the error disappeared?

Comment: Then the above error is gone, but other errors are coming.

"The above error occurred in the <Row> component:
.
.
.
Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
     Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries."


it gives dozens of errors sir

Comment: Don't panic. Please provide a minimal, reproducible code example. We don't know what are you trying to test and what happens without seeing your code